# Prove the equation $\ln(x) = \frac1 {x-1}$ has exactly 2 real solutions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, roots

> Prove the equation $\ln(x) = \frac1 {x-1}$ has exactly 2 real solutions.

Hello all. I thought of defining the function $f(x)=x-e^{\frac 1 {x-1}}$ and showing it has only 2 single roots, though I am not sure on how to show it and I understand it is better to prove using Lagrange's theorem.
Would be happy to get some help on that question, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ defined on $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ by $$f(x) = (x-1)\ln x\,.$$
We have 
$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$, $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) =+\infty$. Further, $f$ is differentiable twice on its domain, with
$$
f''(x)  = \frac{x+1}{x^2} > 0
$$
and
$$
f'(x)  = 1+\ln x - \frac{1}{x}
$$
which has limit $0$ at $x=1$ (on both sides), $-\infty$ at $0^+$ and $+\infty$ at $\infty$.Combining the two *(the limits of $f'$ and the fact that $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$, and strictly increasing on $(1,\infty)$)*, $f' <0$ on $(0,1)$ and $f'>0$ on $(1,\infty)$, i.e. you have strict monotonicity of $f$ on both parts of its domain.

From this last thing, along with the limits of $f$, you get the result: $f$ takes the value $1$ exactly once on $(0,1)$, and exactly once on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Why would you leave $1$ out of the domain of $f$?

Comment: @orangeskid You don't need to, but the original problem leaves out $1$ (for obvious reasons: not defined), so it makes sense to not worry about $x=1$ in the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Consider and study the function $f(x)=(x-1)\log x-1$ using derivatives and IVT to prove that we have exactly 2 solutions for $f(x)=0$.

Comment: The IVT will give existence; the "exactly $2$" requires something else.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes of course, strictly monotonicity!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=ln(x)- \frac{1}{1-x}$ and then differentiate it once and look at how many times this function changes monotony

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:  On $(1,\infty)$, $x\mapsto \ln(x)$ is strictly increasing and increases without bound.  On the same interval $x \mapsto 1/(x-1)$ decreases from $+\infty$ to $0$.  Now apply the intermediate value theorem to see you have at least one root on $(1,\infty)$.  The monotonicities can be used to see the root is unique.  Now deal similarly on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without using a study function, you can look over $]0,1[$ and $]1,+\infty[$.

On both segments, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x-1}$ and $x\mapsto \ln(x)$ are continuous respectively strictly decreasing and increasing : they can have on both segment at most one intersection point. Now looking on the values near the boundaries, and using a corollary of the Intermediate value theorem, you can conclude the existence of exactly one point of intersection on each segment, two in total.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x$ does not exist for $x \le 0$ and $\frac 1{x-1}$ does not exist for $x = 1$.

So if there are solution they will exist on the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1, \infty)$.

On these intervals the function $f(x) = \ln x - \frac 1{x-1}$ is continuous.

$f'(x) = \frac 1x - (-1)\frac 1{(x-1)^2} = \frac 1x + \frac 1{(x-1)^2} > 0$ so $f'(x)$ is increasing on the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. So if $f(x)$ ever "crosses the $x$-axis".  It can only do so at most once in each interval.

Taking the limits of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0^+; x \to 1^-; x\to 1^+$ and $x\to \infty$ we will see that $f(x)$ will have negative and positive values on each of these intervals.  So by the intermediate value theorem there will be values in these intervals where $f(x) = 0$.

And as $f'(x) > 0$ there can only at most one on each interval, so there will be exactly one on each interval.

And, obviously, if $f(x) = 0$ then $\ln x = \frac 1{x-1}$.